# ipython notebook can't find pyzmq

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pyzmq

I get the following error when I attempt to run ipython notebook:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/ipython", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(start_ipython())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 120, in start_ipython
    return launch_new_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 573, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py", line 321, in initialize
    super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).initialize(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/application.py", line 369, in initialize
    self.parse_command_line(argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py", line 316, in parse_command_line
    return super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).parse_command_line(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in parse_command_line
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 471, in parse_command_line
    return self.initialize_subcommand(subc, subargv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize_subcommand
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 402, in initialize_subcommand
    subapp = import_item(subapp)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/utils/importstring.py", line 42, in import_item
    module = __import__(package, fromlist=[obj])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/html/notebookapp.py", line 30, in <module>
    check_for_zmq('13', 'IPython.html')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/utils/zmqrelated.py", line 12, in check_for_zmq
    raise ImportError("%s requires pyzmq >= %s"%(required_by, minimum_version))
ImportError: IPython.html requires pyzmq >= 13
```

I've tried:

`pip uninstall ipython`

`pip install "ipython[all]"`

`pip install "ipython[all]" --force-reinstall`

`pip uninstall pyzmq`

`pip install pyzmq`

`pip install pyzmq --upgrade`

But nothing is working. I've read the other threads on this topic, but none of those answers work. What am I missing? pyzmq is installed at at the latest version from what I can tell. I've reinstalled it about 5 times now.

UPDATE: 
I am running CentOS 7 with Python 2.7

UPDATE:

`pip list` reveals that pyzmq (14.6.0) is installed.

Thanks!

Comment: does pip point to python2 or 3?

Comment: Have you install `libzmq3-devel` through yum or something similar? pyzmq tries to build it if it isn't there, but doesn't always succeed.

Comment: @cge I have it installed, should I try to remove it and try again?

Comment: Hrm... can you import `zmq`? What is the value of `zmq.__version__`?

Comment: @cge I cannot import zmq, I get an error: `ImportError: /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/utils.so: undefined symbol: zmq_curve_keypair`